# Is there a shortcut way to remove null records from List?

Tags: apex

How to remove null or empty values from list in apex.I know i could do that with while or for loop.Is there any shortcut way or method available to remove empty and null values in a list?

Comment: You could use [removeAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) if its a set but list class doesn't have a remove all

Comment: Why did you add them in the first place?

Comment: You can see a [list](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) of all the methods provided by the `List` class.

Comment: No, there are no shortcuts available in Apex. Any technique you use will involve the use of `do`, `while`, or `for`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need a list, or can you use a set?

```
// create a list for testing
list<string> aStringList = new list<string> { 'one', 'two', null, 'two', '', 'three' };
system.debug(aStringList);

// create a set from the list
set<string> aStringSet = new set<string>(aStringList);

// remove blanks and nulls
aStringSet.remove('');
aStringSet.remove(null);

// convert back to list
aStringList = new list<string>(aStringSet);
system.debug(aStringList);
```

The output is:

```
DrozBook:fsb-maintenance tgagne$ force apex < tooter | grep debug\|
08:25:47.17 (18105078)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|(one, two, null, two, , three)
08:25:47.17 (18243825)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|(one, two, three)
```